# Фрагменты ViewPager в фрагментах BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

В общем, есть фрагмент HomeFragment, который выбирается с помощью BottomNavigationView. В этом фрагменте есть еще два фрагмента TabLayout\ViewPager фильмы и сериалы. Если перейти из HomeFragment в другую вкладку(в закладки для примера), то при возвращение обратно, там будет две пустые и криво работающие наши две вкладки фильмы|сериалы.
И собсна, как это дело исправить\переделать?

Код HomeFragment

```java
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    View v;

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;

    public HomeFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        tabLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.tablayoutid);
        viewPager = v.findViewById(R.id.viewpagerid);
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.AddFragment(new FilmsFragment(), "Films");
        adapter.AddFragment(new SerialsFragment(), "Serials");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй поменять на childFragmentManager.

```
adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this.getChildFragmentManager());
```

Comment: Пасиб) теперь всё работает нормально

Comment: @Xakacu9l approved ответ?